# How upload multiple files laravel 3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

i want to upload multiple files to server with laravel 3 but how?
View code:

```
{{ Form::open_for_files() }}
    {{ Form::label('imgs', 'Image') }}
    <input name="imgs[]" type="file" multiple="" />

    {{ Form::label('', '') }}
    {{ Form::submit('submit', array('class' => 'submit')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Routes code:

```
Input::upload('imgs', 'public/uploads' , 'abc.jpg');
```

but it is not working.
anybody help please.

Answer (score 6):

I think, you should do it in foreach loop like this:

```
$files = Input::file();
foreach($files as $key=>$file)
{
   Input::upload("imgs[$key]", 'public/uploads' , "img_$key.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did in my app, (handled by symfony's http foundation)

```
foreach((array) Request::foundation()->files->get('file') as $file) {

    $file->move('save_path', 'new_name');

}
```

name for upload fields should be 'name="file[]"'